How to map two entities that share columns and allow insert and update
I have some entities that share columns. When I try to configure the join column, I get the error: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Aula column: no_entity (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
@Entity
@Table(name = "AULAS")
public class Aula {
    @Id
    private String cveAula;

    //This entity is not null
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_PAIS", referencedColumnName = "NO_PAIS", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_ENTIDAD", referencedColumnName = "NO_ENTIDAD", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_DELEGACION", referencedColumnName = "NO_DELEGACION", nullable = false)
    })
    private DelegacionMunicipio delegacionMunicipio;

    //This could be null, but use the delegacionMunicipio FK
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_PAIS", referencedColumnName = "NO_PAIS"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_ENTIDAD", referencedColumnName = "NO_ENTIDAD"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_DELEGACION", referencedColumnName = "NO_DELEGACION"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_LOCALIDAD", referencedColumnName = "NO_LOCALIDAD")
    })
    private Localidad localidad;

    //This is similar to localidad
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_PAIS", referencedColumnName = "NO_PAIS"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_ENTIDAD", referencedColumnName = "NO_ENTIDAD"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_DELEGACION", referencedColumnName = "NO_MUNICIPIO"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_ASENTAMIENTO", referencedColumnName = "NO_ASENTAMIENTO")
    })
    private CodigoPostal entCodigoPostal;
}

example of tables:
CREATE TABLE DELEGACIONES_MUNICIPIOS
(
    NO_PAIS       NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    NO_ENTIDAD    NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    NO_DELEGACION NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (NO_PAIS, NO_ENTIDAD, NO_DELEGACION)
);

CREATE TABLE LOCALIDADES
(
    NO_PAIS       NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    NO_ENTIDAD    NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    NO_DELEGACION NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    NO_LOCALIDAD  NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (NO_PAIS, NO_ENTIDAD, NO_DELEGACION, NO_LOCALIDAD)
);

CREATE TABLE CODIGOS_POSTALES
(
    NO_PAIS       NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    NO_ENTIDAD    NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    NO_DELEGACION NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    NO_ASENTAMIENTO  NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (NO_PAIS, NO_ENTIDAD, NO_DELEGACION, NO_ASENTAMIENTO)
);

CREATE TABLE AULAS
(
    CVE_AULA      VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NO_PAIS       NUMBER(3)   NOT NULL,
    NO_ENTIDAD    NUMBER(3)   NOT NULL,
    NO_DELEGACION NUMBER(3)   NOT NULL,
    NO_LOCALIDAD  NUMBER(4),
    NO_ASENTAMIENTO  NUMBER(4)
);

If I configure the entity with (insertable = false, updatable = false) and create the field separately it works correctly, however I want to handle them as objects not just as properties like private Integer noLocalidad
@Entity
@Table(name = "AULAS")
public class Aula {
    @Id
    private String cveAula;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_PAIS", referencedColumnName = "NO_PAIS", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_ENTIDAD", referencedColumnName = "NO_ENTIDAD", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_DELEGACION", referencedColumnName = "NO_DELEGACION", nullable = false)
    })
    private DelegacionMunicipio delegacionMunicipio;

    @Column(name = "NO_LOCALIDAD")
    private Integer noLocalidad;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_PAIS", referencedColumnName = "NO_PAIS", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_ENTIDAD", referencedColumnName = "NO_ENTIDAD", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_DELEGACION", referencedColumnName = "NO_DELEGACION", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_LOCALIDAD", referencedColumnName = "NO_LOCALIDAD", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Localidad localidad;

    @Column(name = "NO_ASENTAMIENTO")
    private Integer noAsentamiento;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_PAIS", referencedColumnName = "NO_PAIS", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_ENTIDAD", referencedColumnName = "NO_ENTIDAD", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_DELEGACION", referencedColumnName = "NO_MUNICIPIO", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "NO_ASENTAMIENTO", referencedColumnName = "NO_ASENTAMIENTO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private CodigoPostal entCodigoPostal;
}


Can't do that because

1.@ManyToOne

2. PRIMARY KEY (NO_PAIS, NO_ENTIDAD, NO_DELEGACION)

TRIGGER is recommended here

Maybe you can [edit] your answer and post an example of an appropriate trigger?

The issue is you have two mappings to the same columns in the database. JPA requires that only one be set to control the mapping - this is to avoid issues when they are out of sync, letting JPA know the 'one' to look at when updating or inserting to that column. Your situation is that your compound FK is reused on multiple entities, and expanded upon in the later.
Since the localidad has a 4th FK column not included in the delegacionMunicipio reference, it would make sense to me to let localidad control all 4 FK columns and set delegacionMunicipio FKs to be insertable=false, updatable=false as well as the noLocalidad Integer:
@Column(name = "NO_LOCALIDAD", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Integer noLocalidad;

This would mean that all 4 FKs are set based on the localidadand instance that the delegacionMunicipio is read-only and doesn't matter to much on inserts/updates.
Alternatively ( this works in EclipseLink, not Hibernate apparently), you could use:
@Column(name = "NO_LOCALIDAD", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Integer noLocalidad;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "NO_PAIS", referencedColumnName = "NO_PAIS", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "NO_ENTIDAD", referencedColumnName = "NO_ENTIDAD", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "NO_DELEGACION", referencedColumnName = "NO_DELEGACION", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "NO_LOCALIDAD", referencedColumnName = "NO_LOCALIDAD")
})
private Localidad localidad;

Which will allow both reference mappings to be essentially 'writable', using only the NO_LOCALIDAD value from the localidad reference to control its part of the FK.

Hi Chris, I like your approach about letting "localidad" control the 4 columns of the FK, but the problem is that I have another entity that uses the same FK "delegacionMunicipio", I edited my question
About the second alternative, I have the exception "Mixing insertable and non-insertable columns in a property: Aula.localidad is not allowed" when I remove insertable = false, updatable = false in the locality property
Is there an approach where I can indicate that the primary key belongs to "delegacionMunicipio" and "localidad" just add the JoinColumn with the NO_LOCALIDAD field?

Frustrating as I thought this behavior was part of the spec - Hibernate chose not (or refused) to support mixing insertable/updatable=false within the same mapping. This works great in EclipseLink. So if using Hibernate, you are forced to use a mapping to the partial FKs that you maintain yourself. PITA limitation
